# Is it possible to dual wield the same unique weapon?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can monks (or any class that can equip two weapons) dual wield two unique fist (1-handed) weapons that has the same name?

Comment: Most uniques have the legendary unique as part of their stats, which means only a single one can be equipped at a time.  I'm not sure if that applies to all legendarys, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the items in question have identical names and the Unique Equipped flag above their required level, then you will only be able to equip one of them, regardless of their stats.

Answer (score 2):

You can not dual-wield the same weapon. You can see in [this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-fist-of-azturrasq) thread:

> To anyone and everyone that hasn't played a monk and found a legendary fist weapon. I have personally found 2 of the same weapon with different stats and the game would not let me equip them both. So there for making this weapon a piece of crap considering the fact that **you can not duel wield 2 of the same legendary weapons.**

Answer (score 0):

This is true with weapons, but, while this may seem off topic, it doesn't seem to apply to rings. 
My friend equipped 2 Bul Kathos wedding bands at the same time.

Comment: Unique Equipped goes for everything, from weapons to rings.

Answer (score 0):

I two of the same exact legendarie rings (leorics signet)
Totally did not let them get equipped at the same time.

Comment: Please a screenshot. This may happen when a Legendary gets upgraded in a Patch, then sometimes an old one an a newly dropped one are considered different Legendaries. But please, provide a screenshot.